# rolling 3 months sum and row count from a irregularly-dated set on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get the rolling 3 month sum(value) of each id?

**Data:**

```
+--------------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
| tiq_transaction_id | id            | date           | value         |
+--------------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
|           23980806 | a             | 2018-05-15     | 73614336.7168 |
|           24957628 | a             | 2018-09-28     | 47859499.2648 |
|           25403113 | a             | 2018-11-23     | 40708340.1377 |
|           25771232 | a             | 2019-01-07     | 15180519.2423 |
|           23455679 | b             | 2018-02-27     | 21032280.0296 |
|           24456317 | b             | 2018-07-25     | 8081544.0407  |
|           22963119 | c             | 2017-12-01     | 7570269.5457  |
|           22962927 | c             | 2017-12-04     | 8632491.8602  |
|           22962741 | c             | 2017-12-05     | 7029459.0614  |
|           22982978 | c             | 2017-12-06     | 5147303.2     |
|           22982751 | c             | 2017-12-07     | 7667280.7413  |
|           22982520 | c             | 2017-12-08     | 10090265.727  |
|           23007107 | c             | 2017-12-11     | 4930930.2813  |
+--------------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: what you tried so far? and desired output?

Comment: Have you tried using "ORDER BY" and "GROUP BY"

Comment: Yeah... but I am stuck with how to get the rolling 3 months sum (like a moving sum) on value based on the date that looks random.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL you can use window functions together with an interval definition:

```
select id, 
       date,
       value,
       sum(value) over (partition by id 
                        order by date 
                          range between '3 month' preceding and current row) as running_sum 
from the_table   
order by id, date;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9a32616fc49cd88e137127703a0f8153) (using Postgres)

Comment: Thank you, do you mind elaborating a bit more on defining the 3 month interval?

Comment: @kwknpui: that's the `between '3 month' preceding` part - but I don't think SQL Server supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query. (Applicable for MS SQL Server)

> 1. Get your yyyyMM `dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [date]), 0)`
> 2. use `sum over` your 3 months data based on yyyyMM
> 3. then `group by` id

```
select id, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [date]), 0) as yyyymm
        ,sum(sum([value])) over 
            (partition by id order by 
                dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [date]), 0) 
                    rows between 2 preceding and current row) as Rolling3Months
from test
group by id,  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [date]), 0)
order by id, yyyymm
```

Try [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2fa4f0/1/0)